# How can I increase the time complexity of this algorithm in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, t-sql, combinations

I am trying to generate the combinations of each possible team fitting the rules for a league. I have two different methods that I have approached. One is do everything in one single select.
Mind you there are probably about  16 qbs  32 rbs 104 wrs  32 te's 16 dsts 16 k's and then 168 fx's.  After 10 hours I generated millions of items but it still hadn't worked its way through completely.

```
SELECT 
        QB.name, RB1.name, RB2.name, WR1.name, WR2.name, WR3.name, TE.name, FX.name, K.name, DST.name, 
        (QB.salary + RB1.salary + RB2.salary + WR1.salary + WR2.salary + WR3.salary + TE.salary + FX.salary + K.salary + DST.salary) AS cost,
        (QB.projectedFloor + RB1.projectedFloor + RB2.projectedFloor + WR1.projectedFloor + WR2.projectedFloor + WR3.projectedFloor + TE.projectedFloor + FX.projectedFloor + K.projectedFloor + DST.projectedFloor) AS lowest, 
        (QB.projectedCeiling + RB1.projectedCeiling + RB2.projectedCeiling + WR1.projectedCeiling + WR2.projectedCeiling + WR3.projectedCeiling + TE.projectedCeiling + FX.projectedCeiling + K.projectedCeiling + DST.projectedCeiling) AS highest, 
        (QB.projectedPoints + RB1.projectedPoints + RB2.projectedPoints + WR1.projectedPoints + WR2.projectedPoints + WR3.projectedPoints + TE.projectedPoints + FX.projectedPoints + K.projectedPoints + DST.projectedPoints) AS projection
    FROM quarterbacks QB
    INNER JOIN defense DST
    ON DST.defenseId = DST.defenseId
    INNER JOIN kicker K
    ON K.kickerId = K.kickerId
    INNER JOIN tightends TE
    ON  TE.playersId = TE.playersId
    INNER JOIN runningbacks RB1
    ON RB1.playersId = RB1.playersId
    INNER JOIN runningbacks RB2
    ON  RB2.playersId = RB2.playersId
    INNER JOIN receivers WR1
    ON   WR1.playersId = WR1.playersId
    INNER JOIN receivers WR2 
    ON  WR2.playersId = WR2.playersId
    INNER JOIN receivers WR3
    ON   WR3.playersId = WR3.playersId
    INNER JOIN flex FX
    ON  FX.playersId = FX.playersId
    WHERE 
        RB1.runningbacksId != RB2.runningbacksId AND 
        WR1.receiversId != WR2.receiversId AND 
        WR1.receiversId != WR3.receiversId AND 
        WR2.receiversId != WR3.receiversId AND
        FX.playersId != RB1.playersId AND 
        FX.playersId != RB2.playersId AND
        FX.playersId != WR1.playersId AND
        FX.playersId != WR2.playersId AND
        FX.playersId != WR3.playersId AND
        FX.playersId != TE.playersId AND
        (QB.salary + RB1.salary + RB2.salary + WR1.salary + WR2.salary + WR3.salary + TE.salary + K.salary + DST.salary) < 50000 AND
        (QB.salary + RB1.salary + RB2.salary + WR1.salary + WR2.salary + WR3.salary + TE.salary + K.salary + DST.salary) > 45000 
        AND 
        (QB.projectedPoints + RB1.projectedPoints + RB2.projectedPoints + WR1.projectedPoints + WR2.projectedPoints + WR3.projectedPoints + TE.projectedPoints + FX.projectedPoints + K.projectedPoints + DST.projectedPoints) > 100
    ORDER BY
        (QB.projectedCeiling + RB1.projectedCeiling + RB2.projectedCeiling + WR1.projectedCeiling + WR2.projectedCeiling + WR3.projectedCeiling + TE.projectedCeiling + FX.projectedCeiling + K.projectedCeiling + DST.projectedCeiling), 
        (QB.projectedPoints + RB1.projectedPoints + RB2.projectedPoints + WR1.projectedPoints + WR2.projectedPoints + WR3.projectedPoints + TE.projectedPoints + FX.projectedPoints + K.projectedPoints + DST.projectedPoints),
        (QB.projectedFloor + RB1.projectedFloor + RB2.projectedFloor + WR1.projectedFloor + WR2.projectedFloor + WR3.projectedFloor + TE.projectedFloor + FX.projectedFloor + K.projectedFloor + DST.projectedFloor)
```

I also have another approach in which I may not be understanding clearly if it would be faster.  It involves  making smaller tables and then joining them together.

```
DECLARE @QBSRBS TABLE (
    qb nvarchar(max),
    rb1 nvarchar (max),
    rb2 nvarchar (max),
    cost int,
    highest float,
    lowest float,
    points float
); 

DECLARE @WRS TABLE (
    wr1 nvarchar(max),
    wr2 nvarchar(max),
    wr3 nvarchar(max),
    cost int,
    highest float,
    lowest float,
    points float
);

DECLARE @TEsDSTK TABLE (
    te nvarchar(max),
    fx nvarchar(max),
    dst nvarchar(max),
    k nvarchar(max),
    cost int,
    highest float,
    lowest float,
    points float
);

INSERT INTO @QBSRBS
    SELECT
        QB.name, RB1.name, RB2.name,
        (QB.salary + RB1.salary + RB2.salary ) AS cost,
        (QB.projectedFloor + RB1.projectedFloor + RB2.projectedFloor) AS lowest, 
        (QB.projectedCeiling + RB1.projectedCeiling + RB2.projectedCeiling) AS highest, 
        (QB.projectedPoints + RB1.projectedPoints + RB2.projectedPoints) AS projection
    FROM quarterbacks QB
        INNER JOIN runningbacks RB1
    ON RB1.playersId = RB1.playersId
        INNER JOIN runningbacks RB2
    ON  RB2.playersId = RB2.playersId
    WHERE 
        RB1.runningbacksId != RB2.runningbacksId AND
        RB1.team != RB2.team

INSERT INTO @WRS
    SELECT
        WR1.name, WR2.name, WR3.name,
        (WR1.salary + WR2.salary + WR3.salary) AS cost,
        (WR1.projectedFloor + WR2.projectedFloor + WR3.projectedFloor) AS lowest, 
        (WR1.projectedCeiling + WR2.projectedCeiling + WR3.projectedCeiling) AS highest, 
        (WR1.projectedPoints + WR2.projectedPoints + WR3.projectedPoints) AS projection
    FROM receivers WR1
        INNER JOIN receivers WR2 
    ON  WR2.playersId = WR2.playersId
        INNER JOIN receivers WR3
    ON   WR3.playersId = WR3.playersId
    WHERE WR1.receiversId != WR2.receiversId AND 
        WR1.receiversId != WR3.receiversId AND 
        WR2.receiversId != WR3.receiversId AND
        WR1.team != WR2.team AND WR1.team != WR3.team AND
        WR2.team != WR3.team

INSERT INTO @TEsDSTK 
    SELECT TE.name, FX.name, K.name, DST.name, 
        (TE.salary + FX.salary + K.salary + DST.salary) AS cost,
        (TE.projectedFloor + FX.projectedFloor + K.projectedFloor + DST.projectedFloor) AS lowest, 
        (TE.projectedCeiling + FX.projectedCeiling + K.projectedCeiling + DST.projectedCeiling) AS highest, 
        (TE.projectedPoints + FX.projectedPoints + K.projectedPoints + DST.projectedPoints) AS projection
    FROM kicker K
        INNER JOIN tightends TE
    ON  TE.playersId = TE.playersId
        INNER JOIN flex FX
    ON  FX.playersId = FX.playersId
        INNER JOIN defense DST
    ON DST.defenseId = DST.defenseId
    WHERE TE.playersId != FX.playersId

SELECT 
    qb, rb1, rb2, wr1, wr2, wr3, te, fx, k, dst, 
    (QR.cost + WR.cost + TFDK.cost) as cost,
    (QR.lowest + WR.lowest + TFDK.lowest ) as lowest,
    (QR.highest + WR.highest + TFDK.highest) as highest,
    (QR.points + WR.points + TFDK.points) as points
FROM @QBSRBS QR
    INNER JOIN @TEsDSTK TFDK
ON TFDK.cost = TFDK.cost
    INNER JOIN @WRS WR
ON WR.cost = WR.cost 
WHERE 
    QR.rb1 != TFDK.fx AND
    QR.rb2 != TFDK.fx AND 
    WR.wr1 != TFDK.fx AND
    WR.wr2 != TFDK.fx AND
    WR.wr3 != TFDK.fx AND
    (QR.highest + WR.highest + TFDK.highest) > 203
```

How can I improve the efficiency of this?

Comment: You're looking at hundreds of trillions of combinations to evaluate. If you're going down the brute force approach then the only real solution is faster hardware. Memory is likely to be the real bottleneck so look for something in the region of half a terabyte of RAM. If you share your table sturcture it would be possible to get a better estimate.

Comment: You assume the OP is using Enterprise then, @BarneyL ? Also, I doubt the OP needing 2GB storage for severy columns in their tables is going to help. For example, the OP states that a single row on the table `@TEsDSTK` *could* be over 8GB in size.

Comment: Interesting CROSS JOIN syntax you've got there.

Comment: @Larnu you raise some good points. In reality I doubt there's a player with a name that needs an nvarchar(max) to store but the design could do with some normalisation and narrower data types but there is the potential with two people with the same name.
It would be helpful to know the intention of this. If it's to find the best team then probably finding the best players in each caregory and then combining would cut down the combinations.

Comment: I hadn't even noticed they were effectively `CROSS JOIN`s @GertArnold. Nice spot. Certainly an `ON` clause on a column equally itself is well, for lack of a better world, quite a silly `ON` clause. I suppose it's "inventive" but I'm not sure that's a compliment in this scenario. :/

Comment: If the data isn't normalise, the OP probably has some even bigger problems to deal with, and it's no wonder the query is performing terribly.